# Reset password by mobile number for devise auth token

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We are using mobile number to login in our system where email is optional how can we integrate forgot password we can send password reset token or code. Is there any way we can handle it with devise_token_auth or devise?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm also stuck at a similar problem. Really appreciate if you do have a solution .

Comment: I used sms service and a code to reset password. System sends a sms with a code and user provides that code then reset screen appears. @Purry

Comment: On which method in the recoverable module that the sms notification has to be included ? Would be adding the condition to check whether users email is null, the reset password could be sent to the phone number? We are already using an sms service to send it. Is it on this method ? def send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})

Answer (score 1):

Devise comes with a built in password recovery module called Recoverable. You may find further information on the project's [github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#password-reset-tokens-and-rails-logs)

However, it requires an Email address.

If you don't consider making it mandatory in your application, you may consider connecting devise's Recoverable module to [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/ongair/whatsapi) and send the access token via Whatsapp.

Comment: On which method in the recoverable module that the sms notification has to be included ?

Would be adding the condition to check whether users email is null, the reset password could be sent to the phone number? We are already using an sms service to send it.

def send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})